# make background transparent using mask in java canvas and paint Android - Is it possible to declare an alpha mask

Tags: java, image-processing, canvas, paint

This is so slow can you suggest how to solve this in efficient manner by using Canvas and Paint in java?

```
    private Segmenter segmenter;
    private ByteBuffer maskBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(0);
    private int maskWidth = 0;
    private int maskHeight = 0;
    BitmapUtils bitmapUtils = new BitmapUtils();
    Bitmap maskBitmap;
    ProcessedListener listener;
    public SegmentHelper(ProcessedListener mlistener) {
        this.listener = mlistener;
    }

    public void init() {
        SelfieSegmenterOptions options =
                new SelfieSegmenterOptions.Builder()
                        .setDetectorMode(SelfieSegmenterOptions.SINGLE_IMAGE_MODE)
                        .build();
        segmenter = Segmentation.getClient(options);
    }

    /**
     * Processes a bitmap and informs the listener on success
     */
    public void processImage(Context mContext, Bitmap image) {
        InputImage input = InputImage.fromBitmap(image, 0);
        segmenter.process(input).addOnSuccessListener(SegmentationMask -> {
            maskBuffer = SegmentationMask.getBuffer();
            maskWidth = SegmentationMask.getWidth();
            maskHeight = SegmentationMask.getHeight();
            listener.imageProcessed();

        })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                });
    }

    /**
     * Highlights the detected background of the segmentation mask as a green overlay
     */
    public Bitmap generateMaskImage(Bitmap image) {
        maskBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getConfig());
        for (int y = 0; y < maskHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < maskWidth; x++) {
                int bgConfidence = (int) ((1.0 - maskBuffer.getFloat()) * 255);
                maskBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(bgConfidence, 0, 0, 0));
            }
        }
        maskBuffer.rewind();
        return bitmapUtils.mergeBitmaps(image, maskBitmap);
    }
```

I have created a class ImageProcessor for this and working perfectly fine. But in real-time application this is giving me very poor performance 1-2 fps and I need at least 15fps, and the performance drop occurs because of the for loops in the background changing part, could you help me to do it by using canvas and paint for it.